# Preconfigured VCF w/ QFX5100 doesn't auto-provision some vc-ports

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos

I am currently (trying) to deploy a Virtual Chassis Fabric with QFX5100.

I'm using the pre-provisioned model and got the stack working for now - however, some of the vc-ports do not auto-configure symmetrically on both sides.

```
> show configuration | display set | match virtual-chassis
set virtual-chassis auto-sw-update qfx-5 package-name /var/tmp/jinstall-host-qfx-5-21.4R3-S4.13-signed.tgz
set virtual-chassis preprovisioned
set virtual-chassis member 0 fabric-tree-root
set virtual-chassis member 0 role routing-engine
set virtual-chassis member 0 serial-number REDACTED
set virtual-chassis member 1 fabric-tree-root
set virtual-chassis member 1 role routing-engine
set virtual-chassis member 1 serial-number REDACTED
set virtual-chassis member 2 role line-card
set virtual-chassis member 2 serial-number REDACTED
set virtual-chassis member 3 role line-card
set virtual-chassis member 3 serial-number REDACTED
set virtual-chassis member 4 role line-card
set virtual-chassis member 4 serial-number REDACTED
set virtual-chassis member 5 role line-card
set virtual-chassis member 5 serial-number REDACTED
set virtual-chassis member 6 role line-card
set virtual-chassis member 6 serial-number REDACTED
set virtual-chassis member 7 role line-card
set virtual-chassis member 7 serial-number REDACTED
```

The stack assembles "fine", but the vc-ports between fpc0 and fpc2 and fpc0 and fpc0 and fpc6 do not come up through the magic of auto-provisioning of the vc-ports:

```
> show virtual-chassis

Preprovisioned Virtual Chassis Fabric
Fabric ID: REDACTED
Fabric Mode: Enabled
                                                Mstr           Mixed Route Neighbor List
Member ID  Status   Serial No    Model          prio  Role      Mode  Mode ID  Interface
0 (FPC 0)  Prsnt    REDACTED     qfx5100-24q-2p 129   Master*      N  F    3  vcp-255/0/1
                                                                           4  vcp-255/0/2
                                                                           5  vcp-255/0/3
                                                                           7  vcp-255/0/5
1 (FPC 1)  Prsnt    REDACTED     qfx5100-24q-2p 129   Backup       N  F    2  vcp-255/0/0
                                                                           3  vcp-255/0/1
                                                                           4  vcp-255/0/2
                                                                           5  vcp-255/0/3
                                                                           6  vcp-255/0/4
                                                                           7  vcp-255/0/5
2 (FPC 2)  Prsnt    REDACTED     qfx5100-48s-6q   0   Linecard     N  F    1  vcp-255/0/53
3 (FPC 3)  Prsnt    REDACTED     qfx5100-48s-6q   0   Linecard     N  F    1  vcp-255/0/53
                                                                           0  vcp-255/0/52
4 (FPC 4)  Prsnt    REDACTED     qfx5100-48s-6q   0   Linecard     N  F    1  vcp-255/0/53
                                                                           0  vcp-255/0/52
5 (FPC 5)  Prsnt    REDACTED     qfx5100-48s-6q   0   Linecard     N  F    1  vcp-255/0/53
                                                                           0  vcp-255/0/52
6 (FPC 6)  Prsnt    REDACTED     qfx5100-48s-6q   0   Linecard     N  F    1  vcp-255/0/53
7 (FPC 7)  Prsnt    REDACTED     qfx5100-48s-6q   0   Linecard     N  F    0  vcp-255/0/52
                                                                           1  vcp-255/0/53
```

It looks to me, that the auto-configuration did only set up one side of the link:

- fpc0 'auto-configured' < 0/0 - 0/52 > 'missing' fpc2
- fpc0 'missing' < 0/4 - 0/52 > 'auto-configured' fpc6

```
> show virtual-chassis vc-port member 0
fpc0:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Interface   Type              Trunk  Status       Speed        Neighbor
or                             ID                 (mbps)       ID  Interface
PIC / Port
0/0         Auto-Configured    -1    Up           40000
0/1         Auto-Configured    -1    Up           40000        3   vcp-255/0/52
0/2         Auto-Configured    -1    Up           40000        4   vcp-255/0/52
0/3         Auto-Configured    -1    Up           40000        5   vcp-255/0/52
0/5         Auto-Configured    -1    Up           40000        7   vcp-255/0/52

{master:0}
> show virtual-chassis vc-port member 2
fpc2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Interface   Type              Trunk  Status       Speed        Neighbor
or                             ID                 (mbps)       ID  Interface
PIC / Port
0/53        Auto-Configured    -1    Up           40000        1   vcp-255/0/0

{master:0}
> show virtual-chassis vc-port member 6
fpc6:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Interface   Type              Trunk  Status       Speed        Neighbor
or                             ID                 (mbps)       ID  Interface
PIC / Port
0/52        Auto-Configured    -1    Up           40000
0/53        Auto-Configured    -1    Up           40000        1   vcp-255/0/4
```

The links themselves are fine.

If I configure the missing vc-ports in question manually, like:

```
request virtual-chassis vc-port set pic-slot 0 port 4 member 0
request virtual-chassis vc-port set pic-slot 0 port 52 member 2
```

the links come up and show neighborship. However, after a reboot of the entire stack, the links come up (as manually configured), but don't show a neighbor.

Even if it would work after a reboot, I'd like to understand why those two links don't auto-provision (like the others), and more interestingly, why they don't auto-provision correctly but only on one side. And ideally not have a mixed setup between auto-provisioned and manually configure vc-ports.

Any ideas, or maybe some more advanced vc-port auto-provisioning debugging magic?

Comment: It may not make any difference, but change the priorities to make one always the preferred master. After that, what happens when the stack is powered up one switch at a time? (preferably with FPC0 the 1 fully booted first.) I've seen weird bootstrapping issues many times... with every vendor imaginable.